# Why I am getting peculiar result?

Tags: php

```
$a=(float) 640.81;
$b=(float) 636.85;
$c=(float) 3.96;

$d= $a-$b-$c;
echo $d;
```

Why  am getting -7.7271522513911E-14 this value? It should be 0 right.

Comment: That is basically 0. Chalk it up to rounding error.

Comment: [Floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)